# How to drag an object by the mouse? (opengl)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, picking, drag

I read a lot of materials to drag an object by the mouse and applied them to my project...
But it still doesn't work.
Even the result of gluUnproject seems uncorrect.
(I used stencil buffer to index)

rendering loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    glClearStencil(0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, i + 1, -1);

    }*/
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, -1);
    camA.renderCamera(cube.cShader.program);
    cube.RenderCube();
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, -1);
    camA.renderCamera(cube2.cShader.program);
    cube2.RenderCube();

    if (sMod == 1)
    {
        pick.moveObj(Xpos, Ypos);
        camA.mModelMat = glm::translate(camA.mModelMat, glm::vec3(pick.moveX, pick.moveY, pick.moveZ));
    }

    //swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    //window event
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

part of picking

```
void Pick::moveObj(int x, int y)
{
int window_width = 800; int window_height = 800;

glReadPixels(x, window_height - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
glReadPixels(x, window_height - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index);

printf("Clicked on pixel %d, %d, depth %f, stencil index %u\n", x, y, depth, index);

glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);

gluUnProject(x, window_height - y -1, 0, model, proj, view, &objX, &objY, &objZ);
printf("to 0  // X :  %d, Y : %d, Z : %d \n", objX, objY, objZ);
gluUnProject(x, window_height - y - 1, 1, model, proj, view, &objX, &objY, &objZ);
printf("to 1  // X :  %d, Y : %d, Z : %d", objX, objY, objZ);



moveX = (float)(objX - PobjX);
moveY = (float)(objY - PobjY);
moveZ = (float)(objZ - PobjZ);
}
```

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

command window (when mouse button clicked&moved)

[image]

could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems like you're using shaders to render your geometry, thus I suspect you never actually set `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` and `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`(used in deprecated fixed function pipeline rendering) so their values are probably identity matrices, use your cameras matrices instead.

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76, I set model and proj matrices in the camera class instead of `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` and `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` but the result still seems wrong. `gluUnprojects` keep returning values like this. **X : 342329102, Y : -1070490360, Z : -451031792**  so I assume that only substracting the unprojected mouse coordinates (last pos - first pos) can't make the right result..... What kind of method do I have to use to move obj by the mouse? [link](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial29/tutorial29.html) maybe this one?